# Boost message with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a custom discord bot with discord.py and I want to make a boost message. When someone boosts the server it will send a message at a specific channel, How can I do that?

I have no idea how to do it. I couldn't even find any documentation or article about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no special event but we can make this happen by checking if the user have `server booster` role [image] and then check
if that role is being added using the `on_member_update` event. Here's an example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if 'Server Booster' in after.roles:
        if not 'Server Booster' in str(before.roles):
            print(f"{after} has boosted the server ({after.guild}).")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can I check how if it works perfectly [ I added some embeds and designs ] without boosting the server?

Comment: You can't check that, it can be checked only when someone boosts the server and if the ans works for you, then mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you could do this:

In the guild settings, you can turn on a toggle that sends a message when someone boosts the guild. You can do your thing off of this message.

Secondly, there's the [`on_guild_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_update) event. This has `before` and `after` Guild objects. These have 'premium subscriber' and 'premium tier' properties so you could look at them. Not tried this personally; but assuming boosting will trigger the update event. [Guild object docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild).

Lastly, if the former isn't suitable and the latter doesn't work the way I think it would; you could create a task that periodically checks the premium properties on the guild and then act accordingly. [Task documentation.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Hope that gives you some ideas to try.